# xp_cmdshell transport-level error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xp-cmdshell

Problem: Every time I try execute the following code:

```
master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'
```

I get the following error:

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

I have tried every possible solution that I can find out there.  I don't think it is a permissions issue as I had permissions issues on a different server and followed the exact same way to fix them on that server on this one to no avail.

Any help or ideas on what is causing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you solved the problem, write the solution as answer, not as a comment ;) you can answer your questions if you solved it by yourself! This may be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue and am posting it here for others to see in the future. If I add a period before "master," it executes properly as in

```
.master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'
```

Comment: Thanks @John. This helped me when I was in dire need. Cheers mate!